# What is the difference between 'patient' and 'casualty'?

Tags: differences, semantics, medical

In my experience, the terms 'patient' and 'casualty' tend to be used pretty interchangeably when referring to people in need of medical attention. However, I feel like there's definitely a semantic difference between the two - I just can't quite figure out what it is.

I think any difference might be based on either:

- where the person is in the chain of care (i.e. a casualty becomes a patient once medical care is provided);
- the type of issue the person is facing (i.e. 'casualty' would refer to acute trauma or injury whereas a 'patient' would be someone with a chronic condition being treated over a long period of time); or
- as a relation (i.e. a casualty exists on their own, a patient must be a patient *of* someone like a doctor).

Or maybe I'm mistaken and there is no functional difference.

The only thing I could find online is [this WikiDiff](https://wikidiff.com/casualty/patient) which defines a 'patient' as:

> A person or animal who receives treatment from a doctor or other medically educated person.

and 'casualty' as:

> A person suffering from injuries or who has been killed due to an accident or through an act of violence.

Which seem to suggest there *is* a difference, but it seems to straddle all of the differences I proposed (whilst also suggesting that non-human animals can be patients but not casualties).

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a subtle difference - a patient is somebody receiving medical care (for any reason - not necessarily because they've been in an accident) while a casualty is somebody who has been injured in an accident or violent incident (whether or not they are receiving medical care). There is an overlap because many patients are also casualties, and vice versa, but the distinction is pretty clear I'd say. Someone being treated for cancer is not a casualty, whereas someone who has been injured but does not receive any treatment is not a patient.

Comment: In American English, *casualty* is not used in a medical context. It can be used to refer to injured or dead military personnel, but would very seldom be used to refer to non-military people. (I understand that in British English it is used in a medical context, but cannot draw any fine distinctions as to it.)

Comment: @Mike: In the U.S., if military actions kill civilians (intentionally or by accident), the deaths are definitely casualties. And if a factory explodes, the injured people can also be called casualties. It's not just for military actions. See [this Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2013/04/18/the-texas-fertilizer-plant-explosion-is-horrific-but-how-common-is-this/) "there have been at least 16 unintended explosions of ammonium nitrate since 1921 that have led to casualties."

Comment: In terms of subtlety, this is right up there with the difference between "firefighter" and "husband". Some firefighters are husbands, and some husbands are firefighters. But that's not where the commonalities begin; that's where they *end*.

Comment: It should be noted that "casualty" is sometimes used metaphorically, as when saying that someone is a "casualty" of poor medical care.

Comment: I have been described (UK) as an 'acid casualty' by my friends, but I have reassured them that the state to which they refer existed prior to my experiments with LSD in 1969 and 1970.

Comment: @HotLicks Or that let's say "the hospital became a casualty of cuts in government expenditure".

Comment: @MikeGraham  How, therefore, does the Emergency Department of an American hospital describe the injured people brought in e.g. from a road accident? If they are not "casualties", how are they described?

Comment: @WS2 - A hospital generally will not make a judgement as to what non-medical conditions provoked the malady the individual is being treated.

Comment: @WS2 I would not be able to tell you the real language used in various emergency rooms, as this is a professional setting famous for jargon and technical terms which I have not worked in. I do not think special nouns are needed: *four injured people are on their way from the scene of the crash, one in critical condition* or *a 31-year old woman with severe burns* or *there are over 20 patients in the waiting room who have not yet been triaged* all seem natural enough. The distinction of illness vs. injury is familiar to lay people, though emergency rooms put people on more specific tracks.

Comment: (n.b., in AmE it is usually *emergency room*. The term *emergency department* is of course as coherent as *oncology department*, but the term is not used like it is in British English.)

Comment: British hospitals used to have a 'Casualty Department'; injured or suddenly sick people were 'rushed into Casualty'; these days it's called "the Accident and Emergency department" (A & E); since 1986 there has been a BBC medisoap called 'Casualty', the longest-running emergency medical drama television series in the world, it seems. At the age of 8 my daughter was adept at predicting which 'patients' would 'croak' as she put it (she is now 40, and a senior nurse).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, quite right. I had forgotten that A & E used to be called "Casualty". I wonder why it was changed?

Comment: @WS2 - in the 19th century, 'casualty wards' provided treatment for simple illnesses and injuries to poor people; they were less prestigious than 'outpatients' (who paid). In the 20th century they took on more and more 'emergency' work. By the 1960s the field of 'emergency medicine' was emerging. By the mid-1970s hospitals were setting up "Accident and Emergency" departments, headed by a consultant. Of course, the word 'Casualty' persisted in popular speech and the media for a while longer. Interesting article in the British Medical Journal [here](https://emj.bmj.com/content/17/5/314)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The TV soap is still called "Casualty"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your research pretty much captures it:

- Someone suffering injuries is a *casualty* (and continues to be so even if they die from their injuries).
- Someone receiving medical care is a *patient* (and ceases to be, when they leave that care).

One often leads to the other (i.e the casualty is also a patient), but that's not inevitable.  Some casualties die before help can reach them, and many patients are treated for conditions that aren't injuries.

---

I think you're reading too much when you say that it suggests, "*non-human animals can be patients but not casualties*".  That's not the case - for example, in the cave rescue team of which I'm a member, an animal may well be a casualty and perhaps also become a patient (more often than not, just require extrication and then be happily on its way, none the worse).

Comment: In the U.S., we wouldn't use *casualty* for an automobile accident; just for military actions and for accidents (like fires) that have the potential to injure a large number of people.

Comment: I didn't know that @Peter.  That's certainly different to Britain (all parts that I've been to) where people hurt in road accidents and other relatively small accidents are indeed *casualties*, but I have much less knowledge of North America, Australia and other English-speaking regions.